# GeoTIFF layer display issue on GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I have published a bioclim GeoTIFF layer on GeoServer but it looks very different from how it renders on QGIS. I am not able to figure what is the issue. Have attached a screenshot of the layer on both GeoServer and QGIS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you style the layer in QGIS and in GeoServer? you can save your QGIS style as an SLD and import that into GeoServer

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution on this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326593/geoserver-not-displaying-geotiff-file)

Appears like the layer needs to be exported from qgis as a rendered layer and not as a raw data.

Comment: I think that the correct way would rather be to use raw image and a reasonable SLD file for visualizing the data with GeoServer.